# Spring Boot: MockMvc returning empty body for POST request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I'm writing a small demo application with Spring Boot and Spring Data Rest.  I have the following model and corresponding repository:

```java
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String jobTitle;

    public Employee() {
    }

    ... // getters and setters
}
```

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "employees", path = "employees")
public interface EmployeeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Employee, Long> {
    @RestResource(path = "by-last-name", rel = "by-last-name")
    Page<Employee> findByLastNameIgnoreCase(Pageable pageable, @Param("lastName") String lastName);

    @RestResource(path = "by-job-title", rel = "by-job-title")
    Page<Employee> findByJobTitleIgnoreCase(Pageable pageable, @Param("jobTitle") String jobTitle);
}
```

If I make the following request through Postman:

```
POST localhost:8080/employees
{"firstName":"Test","lastName":"McTest","jobTitle":"Tester"}
```

I receive a full response body with my newly created entity:

```json
{
  "firstName": "Test",
  "lastName": "McTest",
  "jobTitle": "Tester",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/employees/120"
    },
    "employee": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/employees/120"
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I make the same request through my tests as shown below, I get an empty response body:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = Application.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class EmployeeIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Test
    public void testAddEmployee() throws Exception {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setFirstName("Test");
        employee.setLastName("McTest");
        employee.setJobTitle("Tester");

        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = post("/employees")
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(employee));

        mvc
                .perform(requestBuilder)
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.firstName", Matchers.is("Test"))); // Fails, because content is empty. 
    }
}
```

For what it's worth, if I then perform a `GET /employees` in my test, I do in fact see the entity in the response body so I know it's being created.

My expectation is that I would get the same response through either method, alas that's not the case currently, and it seems as though `POST` requests with `MockMvc` aren't returning a body.  Am I potentially missing a configuration setting somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Setting the HTTP Accept header in the request should cause a response body to be returned:

```java
MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = post("/employees")
        .accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(employee));
```

By default Spring Data REST will only return a response body if the HTTP Accept header is specified.  This behavior is documented in the [Spring Data REST Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.collection-resource.supported-methods.post):

> The `POST` method creates a new entity from the given request body. By default, whether the response contains a body is controlled by the `Accept` header sent with the request. If one is sent, a response body is created. If not, the response body is empty and a representation of the resource created can be obtained by following link contained in the `Location` response header. This behavior can be overridden by configuring `RepositoryRestConfiguration.setReturnBodyOnCreate(…)` accordingly.

My guess is that your Postman request is setting the "Accept" header, which is why you hadn't seen this behavior in Postman.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by explicitly setting

```
@Override
public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
    config.setReturnBodyForPutAndPost(true);
}
```

inside of a `@Configuration` class that implements `RepositoryRestConfigurer`

My guess would be that this is set implicitly for main code, but not for tests.